# Detecting which application is using which network interface

Tags: linux, network-interface

Is it possible to see which application is using which network interface?

For instance, if I have a wifi connection and a LAN cable, is there a way to get a clear answer "skype: eth0" or "google chrome: wlan0" ?

Comment: On a very high level, you want to join the outputs of `ps`(name to pid), `netstat` (pid to remote IP) and the routing information (IP to interface), but bear in mind that a program might be communication with multiple partners over several interfaces at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I think , you should just capture the packets using wire-shark or tcpdump and see which application is using which ip ( and hence interface) for communication by looking at the addresses.

**Update1**

You can grab the process ids by `pgrep` command and then use this command:

```
   lsof -Pan -p PID -i
```

Example:

```
pgrep firefox
23533

lsof -Pan -p 23533 -i
 COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
 firefox 23533 iahmad   73u  IPv4 1317376      0t0  TCP   137.138.52.207:59237->104.16.116.182:80 (ESTABLISHED)
 firefox 23533 iahmad   74u  IPv4 1317600      0t0  TCP 137.138.52.207:46223->66.220.158.19:443 (ESTABLISHED)
 firefox 23533 iahmad   75u  IPv4 1316597      0t0  TCP 137.138.52.207:32950->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
 firefox 23533 iahmad   79u  IPv4 1317730      0t0  TCP 137.138.52.207:32989->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
 firefox 23533 iahmad   80u  IPv4 1317759      0t0  TCP 137.138.52.207:45125->31.13.71.7:443 (ESTABLISHED)
```

so 137.138.52.207 is my eth0 if i do `ip a s` command. There firefox is using eth0.

For skype:

```
   pgrep skype
   24611
```

and then do:

```
   lsof -Pan -p 24611 -i
```

will show the interface for skype as well.

Comment: tcpdump is a good start, though do you have anything else? I ask for very specific things because of the application I wish to start writing though I can work with tcpdump if nothing else but it will make things tricky

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @user1779617 If you need programmatic access, use the library that tcpdump is based on: libpcap

Comment: @Gilles I am programming my application in python, I assume this libpcap is available via ?

Comment: @ silverpenguin use the pypcap library , https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap

Comment: But you can also run the commands in answer,  in python as well. using os.system or subprocess commands

Comment: @IjazKhan yes i know about the sub process...looks like il have to do it that way all version of linux i have tried cant install pypcap or libcap.. both apprently have errors ..

Answer (score 0):

Some of us are very cautious about using tcpdump during working hours. It could add 25% additional processing time to each packet received, as shown by `strace(1)`, so on a busy system utilizing it during the hours when it may be the most handy is not really an option (people complain when network processing times increase by 25% on an interface experiencing high traffic flow). So, tcpdump may be out.

Steps to take when tcpdump is not an option:

First, take a look at your interfaces. See which ones might have high throughput:

```
human=-h  # Make this empty if you want full output: human=""

{ echo . interface . \\ bytes pkts err drop ovrrun mcast \\ . \\ bytes pkts err drop carr collsn ; ip -o -s $human link show | sed -e 's/<.* RX:/RX:/' -e 's/bytes.*mcast//' -e 's/bytes.*collsns//' -e 's/\\  *altname.*//' -e 's/  *$//'; } | column -t
```

That will show you the amount of network packets and bytes through each interface since last system reboot. Output will look something like this:

```
.    interface         .    \  bytes  pkts   err   drop   ovrrun  mcast  \  .    \  bytes  pkts   err  drop  carr  collsn
1:   lo:               RX:  \  119G   366M   0     0      0       0      \  TX:  \  119G   366M   0    0     0     0
2:   em1:              RX:  \  1.30T  1.59G  0     30.4k  0       613M   \  TX:  \  900G   846M   0    0     0     0
3:   p1p1:             RX:  \  23.8G  176M   0     15.3k  0       153M   \  TX:  \  80.5M  698k   0    0     0     0
```

Show a nice display of your ip addresses:

```
/usr/sbin/ip -o -4 a | sed -e 's/^.*: //' -e '/host lo/d' -e 's/ brd .*//' -e 's/ inet //' | sort | column -t
```

This will give you output like this:

```
em1        10.172.10.44/23
p1p1       10.173.43.190/24
```

Next, on the interfaces with high utilization (we'll assume we're interested in p1p1 in this scenario), do this:

```
ss -tulpn | grep 10.173.43.190
```

This will give you output like this, and show connecting and listening processes on that interface:

```
udp    UNCONN     0      0      10.173.43.190:28003                 *:*                   users:(("Main",pid=235446,fd=51))
tcp    LISTEN     0      5      10.173.43.190:21000                 *:*                   users:(("httpd",pid=54079,fd=17))
```

Your process pid's are displayed there.

You can also find multicast listeners (ipv4-based example given because of the "dev inet" option):

```
ip -o maddr show dev inet | grep p1p1
```

Gives an output like this:

```
8:      p1p1\   inet  239.164.10.1
```

And then you can check your `ss -tulpn | grep 239.164` command output, as per the above. However, there are caveats- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892675/listing-multicast-sockets  Specifically: "a multicast socket is not bound to an address, it only participates in a multicast group (IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP). A socket can join multiple different groups on the same interface, or same group on different interfaces"

I have seen pid's show up in that `ss` output, but I've also seen some multicast groups missing in that output. I'm not sure why the multicast would show up in `ip -o maddr show` but not in `ss`, it may have something to do with applications using kernel bypass (just a guess).